# Moq abstract class methods results

Tags: c#, moq, abstract-class

```
public class Derived : BaseClass 
{
    public string PrintStringValue(string value)
    {
        var baseValue = base.GetTestString(value);
    
        return baseValue;
    }
}


public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string GetTestString(string value)
    {
        return value + "from base class";
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class TestDerivedClass
{
    private Mock<BaseClass> _mockBaseClass;
    
    [SetUp]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _mockBaseClass = new Mock<BaseClass>();
    }
    
    [Test]
    public void TestDerived()
    {
        _mockBaseClass.Setup(x => x.GetTestString(It.IsAny<String>())).Returns("My Mocked string value");
        
        var result = GetDerived().PrintStringValue(It.IsAny<String>());
        
        Assert.AreEqual("My Mocked string value", result); //this fails since the base method is 
called
    }
    
    private Derived GetDerived()
    {
        return new Derived();
    }
}
```

What I would like to know is if it's possible to have the mocked result(*"My Mocked string value"*) returned when the **base.GetTestString(value)** gets executed in the derived class and not the **return value + "from base class"**, which is actually returned.

Comment: Don't you want to mock the derived class with `CallBase = true` on the Mock?

Comment: @John I need to have the result of the base method implementation mocked, same if you would have an interface instead of an abstract class.

Comment: So, the sut in this case is the Derived class, and not the BaseClass.

Comment: Then mock `Derived`! There is no way whatsoever that you can mock `BaseClass` and have it affect `Derived`.

Comment: I've also tried that, but it s still executing the BaseClass method

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Derived` class to call `this` not `base` so that you're not explicitly using the base class' implementation:

```
public string PrintStringValue(string value)
{
    var baseValue = this.GetTestString(value);
    return baseValue;
}
```

And then mock `Derived`, since you can't mock `BaseClass` and have it affect `Derived`:

```
var mock = new Mock<Derived>() { CallBase = true };
mock.Setup(x => x.GetTestString(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("Hello");
var obj = mock.Object;
Assert.Equal("Hello", obj.PrintStringValue("abc"));
```

The reason why you can't mock `BaseClass` and have it affect `Derived` is because Moq effectively creates a derived class on the fly with your mock's changes.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but having *this* instead of *base* will not make a difference since the this will refer to the base method since there isn't a implementation in the derived class for it. Also, what I would need is that the *baseValue* to take the value from the mocked returned result when the test is executed. Let's assume that after **var baseValue = this.GetTestString(value);** there is an if statement that checks if the base value is different from the one returned from the base class and I want to go pass that if statement.

Comment: @sixfeet Did you read both parts of my answer? Mock `Derived`. If you don't want to do that, then assume `GetTestString` is part of the internal logic and just don't test it explicitly. Just test `PrintStringValue` and check that it behaves as expected.

Comment: If both of these are problematic for you, perhaps `GetTestString` doesn't belong in `BaseClass` or its derivatives at all.